# How to extend polars api without creating a namespace

Tags: python-polars

Let's say we want to create a single expression and we want to add it to the api.

We can do it through a namespace as [seen here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api.html) but can we add it directly to Expr?

In other words instead of:

```
@pl.api.register_expr_namespace("greetings")
class Greetings:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr

    def hello(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return (pl.lit("Hello ") + self._expr).alias("hi there")

pl.DataFrame(data=["world", "world!", "world!!"]).select(
    [
        pl.all().greetings.hello(),
    ]
)
```

is there a way to make `pl.all().hello()` available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to assign custom methods directly onto the base `Expr` class, though extension namespaces are definitely a cleaner way to handle it (especially if you are going to have more than one related function). Using the same example as above:

```py
# declare method (with implicit 'self')
def hello( self ) -> pl.Expr:
    return ( pl.lit("Hello ") + self ).alias( "hi there" )

# assign the method to the expression base class
pl.Expr.hello = hello

# can now call the assigned method from any Expr
pl.DataFrame(
    data = ["world", "world!", "world!!"]
).select(
    pl.all().hello(),
)
```